# How can I extract the track information from an ID3 bytestring?

Tags: python, mp3, id3

I have a bytestring representing an ID3 metadata container. I want to discard all meta information (=> I want to crop the string) so that only the actual audio data is left. How do I do that (in Python)? I was unable to locate the data inside the bytestring.

Pseudo-Code

```
content = ID3_bytestring
content = content[start_of_audio_data:end_of_audio_data]
```

Comment: You will need to parse the MP3 file yourself or use some third-party module that does it. If you made an attempt, please add the code to your question.

Comment: @martineau I wanted to use `AudioSegment(bytestr, ...)` which didn't work due to the meta information in `bytestr` which is why, originally, I wanted to get rid of it. But I found `AudioSegment.from_file_using_temporary_files(inmemory_file_containing_bytestr)` which somehow works even with meta information. So, I don't really need an answer anymore and I am unsure how to proceed now. Do I leave the question open or do I delete it?

Comment: `AudioSegment` sounds like you *are* indeed (trying) to use some third-party module. Regardless, if you no longer need an answer, might as well delete this question.